# Regex for a subdomain that allows `wwwboys.domain.com`

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will give me the following results from each example and I can't seem to get it right:

`example.com` yields -> nothing / empty

`www.example.com` yields -> nothing / empty

`account.example.com` yields -> `account`

`mywww.example.com` yields -> `mywww`

`wwwboys.example.com` yields -> `wwwboys`

`cool-www.example.com` yields -> `cool-www`

So, it doesn't matter if they use 'www' in the subdomain, but it can't be only 'www'. It can also contain hyphens.

Comment: what language? and `cool-www.example.com` should yield `cool-www` right?

Comment: @ghostdog74 Yes, that's right. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mystrings="""
example.com
www.example.com
account.example.com
mywww.example.com
wwwboys.example.com
cool-www.example.com
"""

junk=["example.com","www.example.com"]
for url in mystrings.split("\n"):
    if url and not url.strip() in junk:
       print "-->",url.split(".",2)[0]
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
--> account
--> mywww
--> wwwboys
--> cool-www
```

Comment: @ghostdog74 +1 Wow, so no re module needed? Thanks.

Comment: @ghostdog74 On second thought, that's way better. Now I can have a configuration setting to add more default not-allowed subdomains (like `api.example.com`, etc).

Comment: This fails for other input, like "www.google.com" or "www.stackoverflow.com", because it doesn't really check if the subdomain is "www".

Comment: right, but OP's sample strings is just that, all with "example.com". "example.com" may be "google.com" for all you know.

Comment: @Roger @ghost It's OK. It showed me what I needed to make my function. I'll post an extra answer below with my solution built on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
x="""example.com yields -> nothing / empty

www.example.com yields -> nothing / empty

account.example.com yields -> account

mywww.example.com yields -> mywww

wwwboys.example.com yields -> wwwboys

cool-www.example.com yields -> cool-www"""

>>> re.findall("^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.(?<!^www\.)[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z]+",x,re.MULTILINE)
['account', 'mywww', 'wwwboys', 'cool-www']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution based on ghostdog74's example:

```
OFF_LIMITS = ('api', 'www', 'secure', 'account')

def get_safe_subdomain_or_none(host):
    subdomain = None
    L = host.split('.')
    if len(L) is 3 and not L[0] in OFF_LIMITS:  # 3 ensures that you don't have a sub-sub domain, and that you don't have just `example.com`
        subdomain = L[0]
    return subdomain
```

Comment: Use == instead of *is* with numbers.  What about "www.blah.example.com"?

Comment: @Roger In the case of `www.blah.example.com`, it returns `None` as it should, but I could modify it to sort out sub-sub domains. Also, I only used `is` instead of `==` because `is` is sort of like `===` and I know that it needs to be exactly `3`. Is that frowned upon in the Python world for esoteric style reasons or is it bad practice? Either way, I can change it.

Comment: I asked about www.blah... because it wasn't clear to me what behavior you wanted in that case.  *is* is not sort of like ===; *is* checks object identity, while === (in other languages) checks value and type.  You will almost exclusively use *is* with None and similar singletons.

Comment: @Roger Roger that. I read that before, but for some reason it didn't stay very long. Thank you.